# Change selection color in TeXShop

Tags: highlighting, texshop

I'm working with TeXShop (Mac OS) and I want to change the color of text selection.

If I want to search for special words with CMD+F, the program highlights the text in a light gray color... Every time I have to search the selected position, because I couldn't find it immediately. If the selection color were red or something like that, this problem would disappear.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The light grey colour is due to the fact that the window in focus is the search panel.  If you find something and then click on the source window, the highlight will change to the system highlight colour. This can be changed using the system preferences.  The system default may be some form of grey too.

Here is the System Preference panel where the highlight colour can be changed:

[image]

If you choose 'Other' you will get a colour palette and you can choose any colour you like.

To see the difference in the focus, here are two images.  The first, is when focus is in the Search Panel:

[image: search panel focus]

Now when I select the source window, the highlight changes to my selected colour (in this case bright yellow).

[image: source panel focus]

But the behaviour of highlights in windows that are not in focus is not changeable, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

In the CMD+F search window, if you click the "Highlight" button in the lower left, it will highlight all occurrences of the search text in the document. The highlight colour used can be selected in the TeXShop preferences - the default is a bright magenta. This shows up in the document window even when the search window has focus.