# Color of highlighting of search result in Texshop

Tags: color, texshop, highlighting

I am using the ogrekit find in Texshop on a mac.
When TeXShop finds a string, the string is highlighted in grey,
which is difficult to see in dark mode (with a background in black).

How can I change it?

Comment: You mean like a TexShop theme? https://github.com/monikajaskolka/TeXShop-Themes

Comment: In Preferences Themes, the Dark Mode Theme is set to DarkTheme.

Comment: This may be helpful. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151399